# Finding the largest prime factor of 600851475143

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, math

I'm trying to use a program to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143. This is for Project Euler here: http://projecteuler.net/problem=3

I first attempted this with this code:

```
    #Ruby solution for http://projecteuler.net/problem=2
    #Prepared by Richard Wilson (Senjai)

    #We'll keep to our functional style of approaching these problems.
    def gen_prime_factors(num) # generate the prime factors of num and return them in an array
      result = []
      2.upto(num-1) do |i| #ASSUMPTION: num > 3
        #test if num is evenly divisable by i, if so add it to the result.
        result.push i if num % i == 0
        puts "Prime factor found: #{i}" # get some status updates so we know there wasn't a crash
      end
      result #Implicit return
    end

#Print the largest prime factor of 600851475143. This will always be the last value in the array so:
puts gen_prime_factors(600851475143).last #this might take a while
```

This is great for small numbers, but for large numbers it would take a VERY long time (and a lot of memory).

Now I took university calculus a while ago, but I'm pretty rusty and haven't kept up on my math since.

I don't want a straight up answer, but I'd like to be pointed toward resources or told what I need to learn to implement some of the algorithms I've seen around in my program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a couple problems with your solution.  First of all, you never test that `i` is prime, so you're only finding the largest factor of the big number, not the largest prime factor.  There's a Ruby library you can use, just `require 'prime'`, and you can add an `&& i.prime?` to your condition.

That'll fix inaccuracy in your program, but it'll still be slow and expensive (in fact, it'll now be even more expensive).  One obvious thing you can do is just set `result = i` rather than doing `result.push i` since you ultimately only care about the last viable `i` you find, there's no reason to maintain a list of all the prime factors.

Even then, however, it's still very slow.  The correct program should complete almost instantly.  The key is to shrink the number you're testing up to, each time you find a prime factor.  If you've found a prime factor `p` of your big number, then you don't need to test all the way up to the big number anymore.  Your "new" big number that you want to test up to is what's left after dividing `p` out from the big number as many times as possible:

`big_number = big_number/p**n`

where `n` is the largest integer such that the right hand side is still a whole number.  In practice, you don't need to explicitly find this `n`, just keep dividing by `p` until you stop getting a whole number.

Finally, as a **SPOILER** I'm including a solution below, but you can choose to ignore it if you still want to figure it out yourself.

```
require 'prime'

max = 600851475143; test = 3

while (max >= test) do
  if (test.prime? && (max % test == 0))
    best = test
    max = max / test
  else
    test = test + 2
  end
end

puts "Here's your number: #{best}"
```

**Exercise**: Prove that `test.prime?` can be eliminated from the `if` condition.  [Hint: what can you say about the smallest (non-1) divisor of any number?]
**Exercise**: This algorithm is slow if we instead use `max = 600851475145`.  How can it be improved to be fast for either value of `max`?  [Hint: Find the prime factorization of 600851475145 by hand; it's easy to do and it'll make it clear why the current algorithm is slow for this number]

Comment: Perhaps you should add the following questions to your spoiler, for the benefit of students: (1) prove (I'd use induction) that in the while loop, `max % test == 0` implies that `test.prime?` is true. (2) Is it likely that computing `test.prime?` is faster than computing `max % test == 0`? What does that say about the value of including both tests? (3) What happens if you change `max` to 600851475145 ? How could you fix this problem?

Comment: Requiring 'prime' enables this: `600851475145.prime_division`. Result: `[[71, 1], [839, 1], [1471, 1], [6857, 1]]`.

Comment: Haha, that's nice. Yeah, the right way is to eliminate the explicit primality check as per rici's comment (aka the first exercise after the spoiler).